# Upload changes to git submodule automatically

Tags: windows, git, batch-file, github, git-submodules

I want to push all of the changes in my submodule to my main repo. When running `> git add *`, it adds all of the changes in my main repo and not the submodules.

```
> git add *

> git status
On branch main
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/main'.

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)
        modified:   Limux/vendor/stb

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
  (commit or discard the untracked or modified content in submodules)
        modified:   Limux/vendor/assimp (modified content)
```

to add these submodules, I need to `cd` to those folders and git add from there. This is quite tedious to do it manually. Is there a way to automate this process? Maybe use something like bat commands or a git command that I don't know about? I am using a windows operating system so please give an answer that works for windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to add and commit changes for each and every one of our submodules. Therefore, we can use this command:

`> git submodule foreach --recursive`.

the `--recursive` tells git to loop through each submodule and the submodules that each one can contain. then we add:

`> git diff --quiet && git diff --staged --quiet || git commit -am <message>`

at the end. the `git diff --quiet && git diff --staged --quiet ||` tells git to run our next command if and only if there are changes to commit.

Here's the full command:

> `> git submodule foreach --recursive "git diff --quiet && git diff --staged --quiet || git commit -am <message>"`

Answer (score 2):

> to add [things in] submodules, I need to cd to those folders and git add from there.

You not only need to `git add`, you also need to `git commit`.  You should then take care to `git push` at the right time (though recent versions of Git can arrange to do this from the superproject; see the `--recurse-submodules` option to `git push`).

> This is quite tedious to do it manually. Is there a way to automate this process?

Of course there is—but automating commits is usually a bad idea, as there's no way to automate the production of a *good* commit *message*.  So don't do that.

Add-and-commit within the submodule should not be tedious.  It can consist of:

```
git switch <branch>  # Use the correct branch.
git add -u           # Add all updated files.
git status           # Make sure the list looks right and
                     # if necessary, add *new* files here.
git diff --cached    # Read through the proposed new commit.
                     # Verify that everything you want is in it,
                     # that nothing you *don't* want is in it, and
                     # that it makes sense as a single atomic
                     # commit.  If not, break it into as many
                     # atomic commits as are appropriate.
git commit           # Write a good commit message, and commit.
```

(Note that the commit message you intend to use for the superproject is quite likely to be inappropriate for the submodule, and vice versa.)

You can use Git's aliases to combine some of these, but each `git switch` should only be used once here, `git add` might need to be used multiple times to make multiple commits, and `git status`, `git diff` with or without `--cached`, and `git commit` should be used as often as needed to make good atomic commits.  If you over-added things you may need to `git reset` or `git restore`, and you might want to use `git add -p` and so on.  So it's pretty rare to have a situation in which it's sensible to do all of this as one operation in the first place.

Comment: Is it not possible to automatically adding all the changes in the submodule, and commit it? I don't mind if the message isn't specifically bout the submodule, it's fine if it's the same as the main repo commit message. I tried the command `git submodule foreach --recursive git add *` and it did the job. But when I tried to commit each one of them using `git submodule foreach --recursive git commit -m "hi"` It gives me some error`fatal: run_command returned non-zero status for [directory]`.

Comment: Of course it's *possible*, I just maintain that it's a *bad idea*. Don't do it. I won't say how to do it because I think it's a bad idea; any mini-script I wrote, I would consider bad. (You still need all the steps: get "on" some branch name in some appropriate way, add, commit. That's a minimum of 3 things to do per submodule.)

Comment: "That's a minimum of 3 things to do per submodule."
this is what I mean by tedious. I have 5 submodules in total, which means 15 actions to do.

Comment: Unless you can somehow know in advance which branch name to use, what to `git add` (perhaps everything), and—this is the really tough one—what to use for each commit message, you can't automate those three steps. If you *do* know that in advance, the automation is obvious (run `git switch` or `git checkout`, run `git add`, run `git commit -m ...` or `git commit -F <file-with-commit-message>`).

Comment: I used the function `git submodule foreach --recursive git add *`  for the adding and it seemed to work with adding all the changes.

Comment: You might want to quote the asterisk or use `git add -u` or `--all` or similar here: remember that, even if you're on Windows, `git submodule foreach` passes the argument through bash, and bash does its own `*` expansion. Remember also that bash will chain commands with semicolon (meaning run them all sequentially) or `&&` (meaning run them sequentially but only if the previous command succeeded). That is: `git submodule foreach --recursive "git switch <name> && git add -u && git commit -m <message>"`. But don't do that, you'll have useless commit messages.

Comment: I don't quite mind if the commit message is not quite sensible. But since you keep on insisting that it's a bad idea, can you give me more detail on why that is?

Comment: It's just because the *point* of a commit is to provide a sensible atomic change. Meanwhile, the point of a *submodule* is to have a repository that's independent of its superproject. If there's some reason to make a superproject commit, that doesn't mean that there should be a submodule commit, nor vice versa: the two are not co-dependent. In particular, the superproject depends on the submodule, not vice versa.